# Mongoose delete nested object at unknown position by property

Tags: database, mongodb, object, mongoose, nested

I know there are several question similar to this one, but none of the ones Ive seen worked for me.
Im trying to delete an object from my collection, which look something like this (but changes often, there may be more nested objects etc.):

```
storage:Array
0:Object
    folders:Array
        0:Object
            stored:Array
                0:Object
                    files:Object
                        name:"1"
                        snippet:"snippet 1"
                        _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd822
                1:Object
                    files:Object
                        name:"2"
                        snippet:"snippet 2"
                        _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd823
                2:Object
                    files:Object
                        name:"3"
                        snippet:"snippet 3"
                        _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd824
                3:Object
                    files:Object
                        name:"4"
                        snippet:"snippet 4"
                        _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd825
                4:Object
                    files:Object
                        name:"5"
                        snippet:"snippet 5"
                        _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd826
                5:Object
                    files:Object
                        name:"6"
                        snippet:"snippet 6"
                        _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd827
                6:Object
                    folders:Object
                        name:"indented folder"
                        _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd828
                        stored:Array
                            0:Object
                                files:Object
                                    name:"indented file 1"
                                    snippet:"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blandit..."
                                    _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd829
                    _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd82a
            name:"test"
            _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd821
    files:Array
        0:Object
            name:"message"
            snippet:"Hello World!"
            _id:60bcafda1e2b8b4a288cd82b
```

I only know the _id property of the object I want to delete (not the position/index), any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: in dynamic array its tough and query will not perform well.

Comment: I expected it to perform poorly speedwise, do you have better idea of doing a file/folder system, where the user can delete and add files/folder? or maybe aggregate could help?

Comment: this is not a good idea to do this operation in mongodb any query in your schema.